# Reference a control's ID created with TextBoxFor()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am *loving* ASP.NET MVC, keeping up with the releases/docs can sometimes be tricky, so maybe I'm just not getting something... I want to use a TextBoxFor(), and working with LabelFor() etc. is fine, all the magic happens for me.

But if I create...

```
 <%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName) %>
```

And wanted to do something nice with jQuery, how would I get the ID of the control that was created? I could add a CSS class and use that to attach my jQuery, but for something I am doing I would like the ID... so I could do something like:

```
 $('#LastName').(...)
```

I know I could work it out in this case, and hack it in manually, but is there a neater way?

Comment: Does this not work? When I try it, it seems to generate the ID as I'd expect it to be named. When you view the HTML source on the page, what is your `TextBoxFor()` outputting?

Comment: This does work and generates the ID that you would expect, but I think that if the framework can work it out for a textbox, it would be able to work it out in other places... Especially useful when the ID is being generated to an array so you end up with an ID like "Websites_0__Url". The manual way works, I just think MVC must know this for me and saves me making mistakes ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since MVC4 there is a built-in way to do it - [@Html.IdFor()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833709%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

[Here is a sample](http://www.nickriggs.com/posts/getting-the-id-and-name-attribute-generated-by-typed-html-helpers/) of using it:

```
@Html.IdFor(m => m.Filters.Occurred.From)
```

and the result is like

```
Filters_Occurred_From
```

Answer (score 12):

I think you can do something like:

```
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName, new { id = "LastName" })%>
```

[Overloads of TextBoxFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor%28VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: This would work in most cases, and I think I had the link between ID and Name too firm in my head, of course I could modify it! I think it would have issues when it was an array that MVC worked out the control IDs for and you ended up with <input id="Websites_0__Url" ...> etc.

Comment: Another way to do it, is to use MvcContrib, which introduces the IdFor method, which lets you do <%=this.IdFor(x => x.LastName)%> which is magical!

Comment: Instead of generating the field identifiers manually I would recommend Colin's approach or if you don't want to depend on MVCContrib then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065307/client-id-for-property-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

As a point of interest it appears that the Html.Textbox() code will generate an id, duplicating the control name for anything that begins with a letter (a-z). If however your 'name' begins with a number it will simply not bother.

This is a fantastic 'feature' that has caused me grief for the past hour or so.

Answer (score -1):

By default your control id is your model binding value, You can also Just use firebug. select the control and get by default control id.